# DynamoDB and NodeJS local tables are not showing up in the DynamoDB admin

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

I am building a Node JS application. For the database, I am using AWS DynamoDB. What I am doing now is that I installed the DynamoDB locally and use the local version instead. But it seems that my application is not sending to the local DynamoDB installed on my machine.

I installed the DynamoDB locally and got it up and running as mentioned in this link, https://cloudaffaire.com/install-dynamodb-in-local-system/. It was running at localhost:8000 at this stage.

Then I created a table running the following command in the terminal.

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name CloudAffaire --attribute-definitions AttributeName=Topic,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=Topic,KeyType=HASH --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 --output table
```

It was successful and got no error.

Then I downloaded the DynamoDB admin to visualise the data in the GUI. For that, I installed the tool, following this link, [https://medium.com/swlh/a-gui-for-local-dynamodb-dynamodb-admin-b16998323f8e#:~:text=dynamodb%2Dadmin%20is%20a%20Graphical,%2Dlocal%2C%20dynalite%20or%20localstack](https://medium.com/swlh/a-gui-for-local-dynamodb-dynamodb-admin-b16998323f8e#:%7E:text=dynamodb%2Dadmin%20is%20a%20Graphical,%2Dlocal%2C%20dynalite%20or%20localstack).

I run the tool and I could see that the table I created is in the UI.

Then I created a table using code in my node JS project. This is my code.

```
// running this file using `node -e 'require(\"./db/utils.js\").createTables()'` will create the table
require('dotenv').config();
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
    region: "local",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
  });
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();



function createTables() {

  const params = {
    TableName: "RegionTest",
    KeySchema: [{
      AttributeName: "name",
      KeyType: "HASH" // HASH - partition key and RANGE - sort key
    }],
    AttributeDefinitions: [{
      AttributeName: "name",
      AttributeType: "S" // S = string, B = binary, N = number
    }],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
      ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
      WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
  };

  DynamoDB.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Unable to create table", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Created table", data);
    }
  });
}

module.exports = {
  createTables
}
```

Then I run the following command in the terminal to create the table.

```
node -e 'require(\"./db/utils.js\").createTables()'
```

The table was created, I got the following output.

```
Created table {
  TableDescription: {
    AttributeDefinitions: [ [Object] ],
    KeySchema: [ [Object] ],
    TableStatus: 'ACTIVE',
    CreationDateTime: 2021-05-23T11:28:28.122Z,
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
      LastIncreaseDateTime: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
      LastDecreaseDateTime: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
      NumberOfDecreasesToday: 0,

      ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
      WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    },
    TableSizeBytes: 0,
    ItemCount: 0,
    TableArn: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/Region'
  }
}
```

When I go to the DynamoDB admin running on localhost:8001, the new table is not there. I could only see the previous table I created using the terminal. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it to use local DynamoDB?

Comment: `0000:table/Region` !== `TableName: "RegionTest"` something went wrong???

Comment: I changed the table name to Region too. It still does not show up.

Comment: Try change `region` to ` 'us-east-1'` instead of `local`

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I changed the region to eu-west-2 which my AWS CLI is using and it is now working.

Comment: You can try this UI tool to lookup your db, tables and indexes https://github.com/webavatar/dynamo-ui